# Is there some command to output only the CPU and Memory usage on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface, cpu, ram

I'm creating a database (research purpose) that receive my PC's CPU and MEM usage (%).

Therefore, I need to output (to a .txt file) CPU and Memory (RAM) usage (%) of my entire system (Linux/Ubuntu 18.04)

The problem is that I'm getting CPU and MEM information separated by processes, using the following command:

```
>> while true; do (echo "%CPU %MEM $(date)" && ps -e -o pcpu,pmem --sort=pcpu | cut -d" " -f1-5 | tail) > test.txt; sleep 5; done
```

Which gives the following output:

```
%CPU %MEM wed jan  9 11:26:39 -03 2019
 0.0  0.0
 0.1  0.2
 0.1  1.4
 0.1  1.6
 0.4  1.4
 0.6  2.8
 1.0  2.4
 1.5  6.1
 4.1  0.6
12.4  8.2
```

I know that this command sorts by pcpu (the most "in-use processes", I guess), but I've only found this way to collect this data.

The point is:

Is there a command to collect CPU and MEM usage (in %) without all these lines? I need only the percentage (the numbers) to use in the database with only the resultant usage of the system, something like this:

```
%CPU %MEM wed jan  9 11:26:39 -03 2019
 53.0 32.2
```

Comment: Don't use `ps`, use `top` for this.

Comment: Note that `ps` shows CPU usage for the entire lifetime of each process.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer...

Comment: Read also about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). It could be relevant

Comment: @Dominique `top` displays a lot of information. There is a way to get just the CPU and MEM percentage with `top`?

Comment: @IsaacBarros: There are parameters in order to make sure you only see `top` results a limited amount of times. Using text parsing techniques, like `grep`, `awk`, ... you can make sure you only see the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace the `tail` command in your script with this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {cpu=0;mem=0} {cpu+=$1; mem+=$2} END {print cpu,mem}'
```

and your line will become:

```
while true; do (echo "%CPU %MEM $(date)" && ps -e -o pcpu,pmem --sort=pcpu | cut -d" " -f1-5 | awk 'BEGIN {cpu=0;mem=0} {cpu+=$1; mem+=$2} END {print cpu,mem}') > test.txt; sleep 5; done
```

Comment: The output (CPU and MEM usage numbers) is blank and terminal gives this warning:


>> isaac1@isaac3:~/Desktop/Test1$ `while true; do (echo "%CPU %MEM $(date)" && ps -e -o pcpu,pmem --sort=pcpu | cut -d" " -f1-5 | awk '{ BEGIN {cpu=0;mem=0} {cpu+=$1; mem+=$2} END {print cpu,mem}') > test.txt; sleep 5; done

awk: line 1: missing } near BEGIN
awk: line 1: missing } near BEGIN
awk: line 1: missing } near BEGIN
awk: line 1: missing } near BEGIN
awk: line 1: missing } near BEGIN
awk: line 1: missing } near BEGIN`

Answer (score 1):

not very elegant or efficient, but here is an alternate solution using Python and the `psutil` library...

a short Python program to print cpu% and mem% would look like this:

```
import psutil

cpu = psutil.cpu_percent()
mem = psutil.virtual_memory().percent
print("{}% {}%".format(cpu, mem))
```

which can be written as a shell one-liner like this:

`$ python3 -c 'import psutil; cpu=psutil.cpu_percent(); mem=psutil.virtual_memory().percent; print("{}% {}%".format(cpu, mem))'`

so you can run it within your shell in a loop like this:

```
$ while true; do python3 -c 'import psutil; cpu=psutil.cpu_percent(); mem=psutil.virtual_memory().percent; print("{}% {}%".format(cpu, mem))'; sleep 5; done
```

(note: `psutil` can be installed on your Ubuntu system with: `$ sudo apt install python3-psutil`)

Comment: Hi, thanks! For MEM works great, but CPU percentage is empty (0%) all the time. I've already installed python (and installed `psutil` with the `sudo apt install python3-psutil` command) but terminal says `"no module named psutil"`.

When I type `python --version` it shows `Python 2.7.15rc1`. I'm quite confused because the `sudo apt install python3-psutil` command should install python 3, right?

Comment: just made an edit.  call python3 not python (or install python-psutil instead of python3-psutil)

Comment: Sorry, still not working (I don't know much about linux commands and terminal stuff). It says `syntax error near unexpected token do'  `

Comment: I've already installed psutil (as you said). I'm quite curious about it because when I go to `python`, then `>> import psutil` ; `>> cpu = psutil.cpu_percent()` ; `>> mem = psutil.virtual_memory().percent` ; `>> print("{}% {}%".format(cpu, mem))` it works (CPU and MEM return the values). But the one-liner command does not work...

Comment: you keep confusing python and python3.  "python" starts up python version2... "python3" starts python version 3.  use one or the other.

Comment: there are packages for installing named python-psutil (this is for python) ... and python3-psutil (this is for python3).  call the one liner with whichever version you install (either "python" or "python3"

Comment: you call the one liner from a shell.. not at the python prompt

Comment: Thaks for explaining! I meant that CPU status still zero. Here's the output:   
`isaac1@isaac3:~/Desktop/Test1$ while true; do python3 -c 'import psutil; cpu=psutil.cpu_percent(); mem=psutil.virtual_memory().percent; print("{}% {}%".format(cpu, mem))'; sleep 5; done


   0.0% 33.1%
   0.0% 33.1%
   0.0% 33.1%
   0.0% 33.2%
^C`

It happens when I call just "python" as well...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirement to just print CPU and memory usage. I created below script. I hope it will be useful

checkResources.sh

```
CPU=$(top -b -d1 -n1|grep -i 'Cpu(s)'|head -c21 |cut -d ' ' -f2)
usedmem=$(top -b -d1 -n1|grep -i 'used'|head -c55 | cut -d ' ' -f10)
totmem=$(top -b -d1 -n1|grep -i 'used'|head -c19 |  cut -d ' ' -f4)
echo "CPU = $CPU%"
echo "Memory = $((usedmem/1024))/$((totmem/1024)) MB"
```

This will print output as below

CPU = 97.0%

Memory = 10230/15867 MB